# Clicking <Link> tags in react-router-dom 4 with react-redux 5 has no effect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm currently using `react` 15.6.1, `react-router` and `react-router-dom` 4.1.1 and `react-redux` 5.0.4.

I have the main `App` component rendered like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('react-view'));
```

The `App` component looks like this (obviously cut down for brevity here):

```
const App = (props) => {
    return <div>
        ...

        { props.loggedInUser ?
        <nav>
            <Link to="/user/profile">Profile</Link>
            <Link to="/user/register">Log Out</Link>
        </nav> :
        <nav>
            <Link to="/user/login">Login</Link>
            <Link to="/user/register">Register</Link>
        </nav> }

        ...

        <Switch>
            <Route path="/user/register" component={Register} />
            <Route path="/user/login" component={Login} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </div>;
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        loggedInUser: state.users.loggedInUser
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(App));
```

The routing works absolutely fine. I can go to `/user/register` and `/user/login` and it will load up those components (and the `NotFound` component for anything else).

However clicking the `Link` tags does nothing. Not even any console errors. It just sits there on the same page. It's the same for any `Link` tags within those components. Middle-clicking works, since that just uses the normal `<a>` behaviour but in a new tab.

I've tried everything in this article - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md which seems to suggest there could be a conflict with how Redux works, but after trying that I still see no difference. As you can see I'm using `withRouter` on the `App` and I'm also using it on all three `Route` components, but I've also tried just passing `location` as a property to the components and that does nothing either.

Adding a `console.log` or breakpoint to any of the components, including `App` reveals that it is never re-rendered when a link is clicked. The location property does have the correct value on the initial page load, for example on `/user/register`:

```
{
    pathname: "/user/register", 
    search: "", 
    hash: "", 
    state: undefined, 
    key: undefined
}
```

However, I console logged in a setInterval:

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(props.location);
}, 1000);
```

And when I click a `Link` it never changes to the new location when it's logged again in the console.

I've seen references to putting `devServer.historyApiFallback = true` in webpack.config.js` but I'm not using the dev server, although I am using webpack. I'm pretty sure that since I'm not using the dev server and just running it directly from express, the history capability should be the browser's default. I have tried that setting though and it made not difference. Here's my config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const settings = require('./resources/settings');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "style.css"
});

const plugins = [
    extractSass,
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
            "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"),
            "DOMAIN": JSON.stringify(process.env.DOMAIN),
            "API_PORT": JSON.stringify(process.env.API_PORT),
            "API_DOMAIN": JSON.stringify(process.env.API_DOMAIN)
        }
    })
];

if (settings.env === 'production') {
    plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true}));
}

module.exports = {
    entry:  [
        './client.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'static'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: extractSass.extract({
                    loader: [{
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: settings.env !== 'production'
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: settings.env !== 'production'
                        }
                    }]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    // These libraries are included in separate script tags and are available as global variables
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        "window": "window"
    },
    plugins,
    devtool: settings.env === 'production' ? null : 'source-map',
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

I know there is another question asking exactly the same on here, but in that one the problem seems to have been the root route conflicting by not using `exact`. This is not the same problem I am having.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. For the benefit of anyone else with this problem, I just needed to swap the order in which the wrapping functions were called for the `App`:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

I can also remove `withRouter` from any other component, even if it has a `Link` in it.